# npm - save installed packages as dependencies

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

I've installed some packages via `npm install $package`, without setting up a `package.json` first.
Now I would like to create a `package.json` file, but keep all installed packages as dependencies.
Simply running `npm init` doesn't offer this option, can I achieve this automatically?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Update January 2016**

**npm** now supports this out of the box. I have npm version **3.5.2**.

so with just a **node_modules** folder with **underscore** installed.

```
npm init --yes
```

then:

```
cat package.json
```

Contained within package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
```

Comment: hmm, when i run this it doesn't do anything.  although, my node_modules directory is in an ancestor folder, so that may be why

Answer (score 25):

**UPDATE:** With the launch of npm v3, this trick will create a lot of unwanted entries on your `package.json` file. That's because module dependencies are now flattened, as @sunny-mittal pointed out.

`npm` doesn't support that, as far as I know. You'd have do reinstall each package passing `--save` to each one.

But, there's a workaround, if your're on Unix based systems. From inside your project root folder, with a `package.json` file already created (`npm init`, as you mentioned), run:

```
npm install $(ls node_modules/) --save
```

and it will reinstall the packages, and save them into `package.json` as `dependencies`.

Comment: It should be noted that with npm 3+, dependencies are flattened quite a lot and the `ls node_modules` trick, while super clever, will end up creating a lot of unwanted entries.

Answer (score 4):

Since NPM `node_modules` is flat now and @Rodrigo's answere don't deal to well with that.

This is what I knitted together.

```
npm list --depth=0 | sed "1d" | sed -E "s/^[\`+-]+\s//" | sed -E "s/@(.*)$//"
```

This is essentially what `ls node_modules` did before.

One-liner to save installed.

```
npm install $(npm ls | sed "1d" | sed -E "s/^[\`+-]+\s//" | sed -E "s/@(.*)$//") --save
```

I'm using

```
$ npm --version 
3.5.3
```

Which lists like this.

```
$ npm list --depth=0
x@0.1.0 /home/victor/x
+-- babel-eslint@5.0.0-beta6
+-- babel-preset-es2015@6.3.13
+-- gulp@3.9.0
+-- gulp-babel@6.1.1
`-- gulp-eslint@1.1.1
```

Comment: In my case, `npm install $(npm ls | sed "1d" | sed -E "s/^[\`+-]+\s//" | sed -E "s/@(.*)$//") --save` didn't work because the tree representation was being returned, so I ran `npm install $(ls node_modules/ | sed "1d" | sed -E "s/^[\`+-]+\s//" | sed -E "s/@(.*)$//") --save` and it worked like a beauty. Thank!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a module called [pkg-save](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg-save).
You can have a try if your npm version is "2.x.x".
I haven't test in npm v3, so I don't know whether it is useful or not in npm v3.

Answer (score -3):

I faced this issue when I cloned a new project from bitbucket. I solved this by the following steps:

1. Go to **root folder** where **package.json** exists in your project terminal.
2. Then run the following command.

`$ npm install`

Comment: That is an entirely different issue. In my original post, the `package.json` file was missing, but modules were located in `node_modules`. What you're describing is the regular workflow for installing modules based on an existing `package.json`.