# saving the already installed package with NPM in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, mongodb, npm

I have already installed "Mongodb" package via NPM in windows without --save option. But can I update the package.json dependency list with mongodb without reinstalling it ?

Is there any workaround in windows for the same question available in the link [npm saving already installed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276345/npm-save-installed-packages-as-dependencies).

Comment: Why can't you just reinstall with the `--save` flag?

Comment: No specific worry to reinstall. But just want to check if there is any way to update the package.json file with the details of already installed packages, right away.

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21123358/2755888

Comment: Its actually little different. Not an exact answer I guess, in windows especially.