# package.json -- How to add already installed packages in 'dependencies' and 'devDependencies' in package.json file after delete package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have added many packages in my Project using **npm**.

But after while cleaning my Project i was deleted my package.json by mistake.

so for create new package.json file i have run command `nmp init`.

now i got the package.json but in my package.json file is like below.

```
{
  "name": "name-will-be-here",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "description-will-be-here",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  " dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Is there any commands for fill the details like before it is...?

but my Question is that...

#### How can i get all details of `dependencies` and `devDependencies` which was already there before delete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm - save installed packages as dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276345/npm-save-installed-packages-as-dependencies)

Comment: You was shared wrong information. Using that command i can see my package.json file code in command line. I want fullfill detail like its before.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you cant.
Longer answer is that you need to understand how npm 3 works by default and that is to install all dependencies and shared sub dependencies in same top folder so your node_modules holds a lot more than your main dependencies only (unless you used legacy option or older npm).

In future use scm like git or ide history features to revert accidental deletions.

Comment: So mate, what happened if we cant fill that detail in package.json?
Is it create any issue in future or in meantime...?

Comment: Start doing npm install --save or --save-dev for the modules you need. It will update it based on your needs

Comment: Whats about past modules details which was i added before delete?

Comment: Like i siad you will have ti do it again including modules already installed

Comment: Yes, i know that, but the Question is that they have to make NPM smart enough.. like if you run command NPM init then it will automatically catch all detail from installed packages...
what you say?

Comment: See my original answer that is not pissible to say from node_modules directory

Comment: Yeah, i have seen that but i am looking for more easy and time saver solution so i am looking and finding another way..

Comment: Sorry you didnt like the fact that the answer is no. No reason for a -1 for time spent helping