# Update package.json after installed dependencies without --save

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I have installed some npm modules without `--save` option. As a result the dependencies were not added in my `package.json`.

Is there any way to add the dependencies of my existing node modules in my `package.json` via npm without having to add them manually ?

Comment: I've got my `package.json` set. So I do not have to run `npm init`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
You may use [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276345/npm-save-installed-packages-as-dependencies)

```
npm init --yes
```

2) npm list command

```
npm ls -json
```

Create backup of your package.json file. Create new one and diff two of them.